# Finding a Dominating function for $-x^3 e^{-tx^3}$, $\forall t > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f(x,t) = -x^3 e^{-tx^3}$

I'm trying to find a dominating, integrable function over $f$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$.  Specifically, I'm looking for a function $h$ s.t. $\forall t > 0$, we have $|f(x,t)| \le h(x), \forall x \ge 0$.  My original idea was to try to show that $min\{\frac{1}{t^2x^5}, 1\}$ was such a function, but it failed in light of this post: [Exponential Function Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225372/exponential-function-question).

I have already shown that

$$|-x^3 e^{-tx^3}| = |x^3||e^{-tx^3}| \le |-x^3||e^{-tx}|$$

so that if I could find an integrable dominator of $|-x^3||e^{-tx}|$ my original objective would follow.  Any ideas?

Comment: You say "for each fixed $t \in {\mathbb R}^+$", but that's not what you're really looking for: you want one that works for all $t > 0$.

Comment: Thanks -- fixed in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such $h$.  In fact, as $t \to 0+$ we have $f(x,t) \to -x^3$, so you'd need $h(x) \ge x^3$, and then $h$ is not integrable.

Comment: What if I restricted the requirement from "for all t > 0" to "for all $t$ in some positive interval (a,b)"?  Then we would avoid the problem of $t$ approaching $0$.  Would this work?

Comment: Yes, if $a > 0$: just take $h(x) = x^3 e^{-ax^3}$.

Comment: Thanks -- that works.  Now I just need to show that such $h(x)$ is integrable.  How would I do this?

My starting idea would be to try to show that that $h(x) \le x^3 \cdot \frac{1}{a^2x^5} = \frac{1}{a^2x^2}$, the rightmost term known to be integrable from a prior exercise (so that since it dominates $h(x)$, it would follow $h(x)$ is also integrable).  This inequality I think would be true if $e^{-ax^3} \le \frac{1}{a^2x^5}$, but this isn't in general true I don't think.

Comment: That is true for large enough $x$ : $e^{ax^3} \ge (a x^3)^2/2$ so
$e^{-ax^3} \le \dfrac{2}{a^2 x^6} \le \dfrac{1}{a^2 x^5}$ if $x \ge 2$.